# VBA multiple checkbox userform to single cell

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am using a userform with multiple checkboxes in it. My goal is to have all checkboxes return their values (unique two letter acronyms) to a single cell. I am not sure how to accomplish this. I have no VBA experience prior to today.

Answer (score 0):

You can record a macro to get your other relevant code for VBA but this should help:

```
Range("A" & LastRow).Value = CheckBox1.Value & CheckBox2.Value & CheckBox3.Value 'etc.
  'Concatenate CheckBox values with "&" (the values will be True or False though)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set linkcell of each checkbox to a different cell -.e.g. checkbox1 to cell A1, checkbox2 to cell A2, etc
For each link cell, use If formula in its adjacent cell to test the link cell's content and return a string or a blank,
e.g. if(A1=True,"AA","") in cell B1,  if(A2=True,"BB","") in cell B2, etc
Finally, concatenate results of 'if' Formulas in another cell: e.g. B1&","&B2&","&B3, using comma as separaters

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you can make a collection of all of the Checkboxes in the form. Heres my code:

```
Private mcolCHK As Collection 'This creates a modular level collection, which will keep track of all of the checkboxes
Private Sub cmdOK_Click()

    Dim objA As Object, strResults As String, i As Integer
    i = 1
    For Each objA In mcolCHK
        strResults = strResults & i & Left(objA.Value, 1)
        i = 1 + i
    Next
    Unload frmTestForm 'rename this the name of your form

    MsgBox strResults
    'instead of using a message box, you can say "strResults = Sheets(sheet1).range("A1").value
    'This part may be customized as needed
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set mcolCHK = New Collection
    mcolCHK.Add chkAtt1  'you will have to add one of these for each checkbox (simply replace "chkAtt1" with the name of your first checkbox
    mcolCHK.Add chkAtt2   'and repeat for each checkbox
End Sub
```

Checkboxes always give a value of True or False. with this method, you will get the number of the checkbox (in order of how you added them to the collection in the UserForm_Initialize() sub) and the first letter of the result (T or F). When i ran this, I had two checkboxes, and checked each one when the form ran. This gave me a result of "1T2T". This can be changed as needed. All you really need is how this all works. just make sure to change all the names to match the names of the variables you used.